# Need a strategy for logging api usage with node.js/express

Tags: node.js, express

The website I'm working on has an api that is accessed from many different types of devices, and I want to get a handle on how much traffic is going to each route.

Right now my thought is to create a new entry in my mongo database every time a request comes in.  This seems like it a very crude approach that could hurt performance.

Is there a good way to go about logging all of this data somewhere (doesn't necessarily have to be to a database) without sacrificing performance too much?

Comment: Buffer logging? buffer X logs then dump them into a single write to the DB. It doesnt have to be safe writes .I'm working on a lib that does that,but it's not production ready yet, you can check winston on the other hand.

Comment: I use Bunyan to write my logs to file as serialised JSON as my long term store for logs which can be bulk inserted into Mongodb for analysis. For 7-day/near-real-time monitoring I run a second transport that forwards my logs via syslog to an external logging service (Loggly). It all gets dumped into an Elasticsearch cluster so you can create search terms to generate charts on user agents and routes